# Keywurl for Safari 5.1 / Lion

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

Has anyone made Keywurl work with Safari 5.1 after their Lion upgrade?

I tried updating the MaxBundleVersion without luck:

```
http://hacketal.com/making-keywurl-work-with-safari-5
```

I'm not interested in using Glims, SafariStand, etc, I just want Keywurl to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now a Safari extension for Safari 5.1 called Safari Keyword Search by Arne Martin Auerlie. It uses new API calls in 5.1 to reproduce all the functionality of Keywurl without the need for a SIMBL hack!

It is still an early version, so the interface is still a little rough, but it works wonderfully.

Get it here:

https://github.com/arnemart/SafariKeywordSearch

Read Arne's blog here:

http://am.aurlien.net/

Also if you don't mind hacks, Safari Omnibar does something similar, attempting to replicate the behaviour of Chrome's Omnibar.

https://github.com/rs/SafariOmnibar

It is a bit hacky, so I would recommend Arne's extension in preference to it, but it is worth watching how both projects develop.

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for a keywurl replacement for a while. But ever since I've seen Chrome's integrated address/search bar, I've wanted that instead. Major kudos for these.